# Как реализовать поиск по Excel, чтобы искал во всех вложенных папках(подпапках)?

Tags: поиск, vba

Имеется рабочий код поиска по множеству Excel-файлов, с выводом полного адреса в виде списка гиперссылок. Как реализовать поиск не только в одном уровне, но и во ВСЕХ вложенных подпапках, с возможностью либо отключения глубокого поиска, либо предупреждения что он включен(думается можно намертво повесить компьютер если выбрать слишком большой объём).

```
Sub ПОИСК()
    Dim folder_$, file_$, s$
    Dim rw&
    Dim sh
'---------------------------'
    rw = 4
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .UsedRange.Offset(3, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        s = .Cells(2, 3).Value
    End With
    If s = "" Then
        MsgBox "Не заполненно поле поиска!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With Application
        With .FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
            folder_ = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With
        folder_ = folder_ & IIf(Right(folder_, 1) = .PathSeparator, "", .PathSeparator)
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    file_ = Dir(folder_ & "*.xls*")
    Do While file_ <> ""
        DoEvents
        If file_ <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            Workbooks.Open folder_ & file_
            With ActiveWorkbook
                For Each sh In .Sheets
                    Set c = sh.Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                            .Cells(rw, 1) = folder_ & ActiveWorkbook.Name
                            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(rw, 1), Address:=folder_ & ActiveWorkbook.Name, SubAddress:=c.Address
                        End With
                        rw = rw + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                .Close False
            End With
        End If
        file_ = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Beep
    MsgBox "Готово!"
End Sub

Sub Макрос2()

    Set c = Cells.Find(What:="жжж", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False)

End Sub
```

Comment: **Excel** правильно пишется.

Comment: *Как реализовать поиск не только в одном уровне, но и во ВСЕХ вложенных подпапках.* 1) отделить ввод-вывод от поиска - выделить собственно поиск в процедуру. 2) после завершения цикла поиска в процедуре поиска получить список подкаталогов и рекурсивно вызывать себя же для каждого подкаталога. *с возможностью ... отключения глубокого поиска* Дополнительный параметр - в ячейке листа, формы, или через InputBox.

Answer (score 0):

Нашлось в бардачке :)

К сожалению, имя автора не сохранилось.

Задействуется *FSO* (*FileSystemObject*). Создается коллекция имен всех найденных вложенных папок.

*FolderPath* - путь к исходной папке. Глубина поиска задается переменной *SearchDeep*. Созданный список папок можно посмотреть в *Immediate Window*.

```
Function FilenamesCollection(ByVal FolderPath As String, Optional ByVal Mask As String = "", _
                             Optional ByVal SearchDeep As Long = 999) As Collection
Dim FSO
    ' применяется рекурсивный вызов процедуры GetAllFileNamesUsingFSO'
    Set FilenamesCollection = New Collection ' создаём пустую коллекцию'
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") ' создаём экземпляр FileSystemObject'
    GetAllFileNamesUsingFSO FolderPath, Mask, FSO, FilenamesCollection, SearchDeep ' поиск'
    Set FSO = Nothing ' освобождаем память'
End Function

Function GetAllFileNamesUsingFSO(ByVal FolderPath As String, ByVal Mask As String, ByRef FSO, _
                                 ByRef FileNamesColl As Collection, ByVal SearchDeep As Long)
    ' перебирает все файлы и подпапки в папке FolderPath, используя объект'
    ' перебор папок осуществляется в том случае, если SearchDeep > 1'
    ' добавляет пути найденных файлов в коллекцию FileNamesColl'
    On Error Resume Next: Set curfold = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    If Not curfold Is Nothing Then ' если удалось получить доступ к папке'
        For Each fil In curfold.Files    ' перебираем все файлы в папке FolderPath'
            If fil.Name Like "*" & Mask Then FileNamesColl.Add fil.Path
        Next

        SearchDeep = SearchDeep - 1 ' уменьшаем глубину поиска в подпапках'

        If SearchDeep Then ' если надо искать глубже'
            For Each sfol In curfold.SubFolders ' перебираем все подпапки в папке FolderPath'
                GetAllFileNamesUsingFSO sfol.Path, Mask, FSO, FileNamesColl, SearchDeep
                Debug.Print sfol.Path, Mask, FSO, FileNamesColl, SearchDeep
            Next
        End If

        Set fil = Nothing: Set curfold = Nothing  ' освобождаем память'
    End If
End Function
```

С помощью *Application.FileDialog* задать исходную папку и использовать коллекцию перед строкой

```
file_ = Dir(folder_ & "*.xls*")
```